# How can I format this data into a bar chart spaced out by date?

Tags: google-sheets

My goal is to take some data and turn it into a chart that looks like this:

[image: chart example]

The X axis shows the values **spaced appropriately according to their date**, and the Y axis shows bars equivalent to value.

My data looks like this (the dates in this example rows do not match the sample image):

```
A                           B          C
date                        status     value

2023-07-17T14:41:47.000Z    ready      4E+19
2023-07-17T02:25:59.000Z    ready      3.8E+19
2023-07-16T02:42:59.000Z    ready      4E+19
2023-07-16T02:39:47.000Z    pending    4E+19
2023-07-15T14:19:59.000Z    pending    4E+19
```

- Date: ISO 8601 date formatted string. May be out of order chronologically.
- Status: Status of the item
- Value: An amount of Ethereum in Wei (ETH is denominated to 18 decimal places)

I want to use the data from only the rows with a `ready` status. I have gotten this far:

- I create 2 new columns, `AA` and `AB`.
- Google Sheets apparently can't format ISO 8601 date strings, so I fill the `AA` column with this function. It filters only rows which have a `ready` status and uses a regex to convert the ISO 8601 date string to a Google Sheets compatible format:

  `=ARRAYFORMULA(DATEVALUE(REGEXREPLACE(FILTER(A:A, EQ(B:B, "ready")), "^(\d+).?(\d+).?(\d+)T.*$", "$2/$3/$1")))`
- I fill the `AB` column with this function. It filters only rows which have a `ready` status and divides by the appropriate ratio to convert the wei value to an ETH value:

  `=ARRAYFORMULA(DIVIDE(FILTER(C:C, EQ(B:B, "ready")), POWER(10, 18)))`

These steps result in a set of columns and rows that look like this:

```
AA          AB
Date        Value

2/8/2023    40
5/6/2023    60
7/5/2023    30
7/21/2023   50
8/16/2023   50
```

But now that I have the formatted data, I cannot figure out how to turn it into a chart that looks like the one above.

The closest I can get is a "Timeline" chart, which respects the spacing of the dates, but uses lines to connect the dots rather than independent bars.

A standard "Column" chart gets close, but it does not respect the distribution of dates. In a column chart, the dates are just labels on evenly-spaced items.

The timeline chart looks like this (again, different data, just an example of what the timeline-type chart looks like):

[image: timeline chart example]

Is it possible to use the data I have to create a chart of the desired format? If so, how? And is there a better approach than I'm currently trying?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the answer. Using my calculated `AA` and `AB` rows, I just needed to use a regular Column chart, and *de*-select the "Treat labels as text" option at the bottom of the "Setup" tab for the chart. Doing this changed the chart from being evenly spaced and out-of-order, to ordered by date with appropriate spacing between values.

The resulting chart looks like this, which is exactly what I wanted:

[image: example solution chart]

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to display the data using a line graph, but I don't know a way of adding individual data labels to the axis:

[image]

The formula in E2 is:

```
=ArrayFormula(let(x,--regexreplace(A2:A,"T|Z"," "),y,C2:C,filter,sort(filter({x,y},B2:B="ready"),1,1),zeroes,sequence(rows(filter),1,0,0),wraprows(tocol(hstack(index(filter,0,1),zeroes,filter,index(filter,0,1),if(zeroes=0,""))),2)))
```